# Indexing of groups of values divided by N consecutives K values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array like that:

```
numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 0])
```

Defined a length (N) and a value (K), I would like to identify sequences of values (including zeros) that are divided by each other by at least N consecutive K, with start and stop index of each block.

So that with:

```
N = 2
K = 0
```

We will end up with:

```
#blocks
[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 0, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9], [8, 10] ]
```

```
#indexes
[ [2, 4], [7, 8], [13, 19], [23, 24] ]
```

In this example block 3 (indexed as 2) also contains 0, that was the selected K value, since there were not enough consecutive occurrences (at least N) to identify two independent blocks.

What's the smartest way to implement this avoiding loops?

As for now I implemented this approach:

```
def consecutive_blocks(arr,K,N):

   d = numpy.diff(numpy.concatenate(([False], arr==K, [False])).astype(int))

   idx_i = numpy.flatnonzero(d == -1)[:-1]
   idx_j = numpy.flatnonzero(d == 1)[1:] - 1
   
   delta = numpy.flatnonzero(d == -1) - numpy.flatnonzero(d == 1)
   
   idx_ii = idx_i[numpy.where(delta >= N)[0]]
   
   return idx_ii
```

This way I get the starting indexes of blocks, but then I need further work to get the ending indexers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 7, 8,
              9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 0])

N = 2
K = 0

b = np.tile(A,N+1)[:N*(A.size+1)].reshape((N,A.size+1)).T
c = np.where(np.all(b[:A.size-N+1]==[K]*N,axis=1))[0]
c = np.concatenate(([-N],c,[A.size]))
d = np.stack((c[:-1]+N,c[1:]-1)).T
e = d[d[:,0]<=d[:,1]]

print(e)
[[ 2  4]
 [ 7  8]
 [13 19]
 [23 25]]   # last zero included (doesn't form a [0,0])
```

- `b` creates a 2D matrix with each row corresponding to a rolling subrange of values of length N.
- `c` finds the indexes of the rows that match the K repeated N times pattern. This gives the starting positions of the [0,0] sub ranges. Indexes representing start and end of array are added to complete edge ranges.
- `d` combines each starting positions with the next starting position to form ranges of indexes.  The starts indexes are increased by N to get to the first Non-K value and the next starts are decreased by one to obtain the index of the last item in the group.
- `e` eliminates the "empty" ranges caused by sequences of more than N consecutive K values.

Based on comments below, better performance can be obtained by changing the first two line to leverage `as_strided` or `sliding_window_view` (*I could only test `as_strided`*):

```
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A,   shape=(len(A)-N+1,N),
                                       strides=A.strides*2)
c = np.where(np.all(b==[K]*N,axis=1))[0]
```

Intermediate values:

```
# b[:A.size-N+1] : rolling subranges of length N

array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  4],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 5,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 0,  6],
       [ 6,  0],
       [ 0,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  8],
       [ 8, 10],
       [10,  0]])
```

...

```
# c : starting index of [K]*N patterns (and edges)

array([-2,  0,  5,  9, 10, 11, 20, 21, 25, 26])
```

...

```
# d : subranges between [K]*N patterns (including empties)

array([[ 0, -1],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 7,  8],
       [11,  9],
       [12, 10],
       [13, 19],
       [22, 20],
       [23, 25]])
```

Comment: What if A wasn't ending with a 0? May I suggest `np.lib.stride_trick.sliding_window_view(A,N)` instead of that `tile/reshape` for `b`. It doesn't copy or move any data, so it is O(1), and instantaneous. And the only difference between your `b` is that it doesn't include a double 0 at the end, but I feel that this double 0 you have is just a weakness in your case (that happens to end well in this case, because last and first 0 combine into a convenient double 0 stop, but you can't count on it). So `sliding_window_view` is faster. And doesn't include deceptive good luck :D

Comment: Then, of course, you need to deal with the special case of the end of the array. And the beginning. But you'd have to do that anyway, without the luck of this example beginning and end 0 combining conveniently.

Comment: `sliding_window_view` is a very good idea.  Unfortunately i'm using numpy 1.16 which doesn't have it.   I did have an issue with subranges at the edges which is fixed now.

Comment: `sliding_window_view` is just a convenient alias for `as_strided` tho. You can achieve the same result (with the same O(1)) with `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(len(A)-N+1, N), strides=A.strides*2)`. Less readable for a human, but same thing for the machine. And, afaik, `as_strided` exists in numpy 1.16 (at least, I am sure `sliding_window_view` was introduced more recently)

Comment: Impressive, this is definitely doing the job! The explanation is detailed and exhaustive, thank you so much. I really like the approach, it's clean and effective.